# Points around the circumference of a circle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Place $n$ points around the circumference of a circle and join
each pair of points by a straight line so that no three of the lines meet inside the circle. Into how many regions the lines divide the circle? I guess I have to guess the formula and prove it by induction...but I have no idea what it would be.

Comment: This is a well known problem with an unintuitive answer (though it is easy to guess the pattern incorrectly if you look at small $n$).  You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_a_circle_into_areas)

Comment: Ok, so question can be deleted now.